# groovy regular expression modifiers... add comments

Tags: regex, groovy

Is there a way in groovy to ignore whitespace in regular expressions and add comments? This is very useful for complicated regular expressions.

Example... I have a DateTime utility class that parses all sorts of variations of a datetime string. Given a regular expression that matches a datetime...

```
if(dateString =~ /(\d{1,4})([-\/\\])\d{1,2}[-\/\\]\d{1,4}(([T\s])\d{1,2}(\:\d\d)?+(\:\d\d)?)?+(\s?[+-][0-9\:]+?|\s?[0-9a-zA-Z\/_\s]+?)?/) {
  ...
}
```

In [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#/x) you can add the `/x` modifier to split up the regex and add comments

```
if($date_string =~ m/
  (\d{1,4}) #month OR year
  ([-\/\\]) #divider
  \d{1,2} #day OR month
  [-\/\\] #divider
  \d{1,4} #day OR year regex supports 01/31/2014 OR 2014-01-31
  (([T\s]) # beginning of TIME :)
    \d{1,2} # hour
    (\:\d\d)?+ # minute
    (\:\d\d)? # second
  )?+ # end of optional TIME
  (\s?[+-][0-9\:]+? # numbered timezone '-0700'
  |\s?[0-9a-zA-Z\/_\s]+? #named timezone 'MST' 'America/Denver'
  )? # end optional Timezone
  /x) {
  ...
}
```

Does something like this exist in groovy? I'm also open to suggestions on how to make this easier to read. :)

Comment: **(?x)** Here is the Documentation http://groovy.codehaus.org/Documenting+Regular+Expressions+in+Groovy

Comment: Thanks @gtgaxiola! This is gold! Additional modifiers are documented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @gtagaxiola I was able to read the [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Documenting+Regular+Expressions+in+Groovy) on how to do this.

I modified my groovy code and ran all my DateTime tests and this regex works great with comments...

```
if(date =~ /(?x) # whitespaces & commments allowed modifier
  (\d{1,4}) # year OR month
  ([-\/\\]) # divider
  \d{1,2}   # month OR day
  [-\/\\]   # divider
  \d{1,4}   # year OR day
  (([T\s])  # beginning of TIME :D
    \d{1,2}    # hour
    (\:\d\d)?+ # minute
    (\:\d\d)?  # second
  )?+       # end of optional Time
  (\s?[+-][0-9\:]+?        # timezone offset '-0700'
    |\s?[0-9a-zA-Z\/_\s]+? # timezone name 'MST' 'America<whack>Denver'
  )? # End optional timezone
/) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to note that in Groovy `/blah/` is exactly equivalent to `'blah'` or `"blah"` - it's nothing more than an alternative syntax for string literals (but one that allows you to use backslashes in most places without having to escape them).  So you can split up the pattern string and use Java-style comments:

```
if(date =~ (
    /(\d{1,4})/ // year OR month
  + /([-\/\\])/ // divider
  + /\d{1,2}/   // month OR day
  + /[-\/\\]/   // divider
  // etc. etc.
)) {
```